# Rule of Thumb for minimum length of time series for AR(1) estimation

Tags: time-series, auto-correlation

I have a data set of 350 points, I want to estimate the lag 1 auto correlation for different sub-sets of the data.

More precisely I want to take non overlapping windows of length 1,2,3....n and calculate the auto correlations of these sub-sets. So for n equal to 2 I take every second observation similarly for n=3 I take every third observation and so on.

Just wondered roughly what the maximum value of n I can realistically work with? Even with n=10 I'm down to 35 observations.

Kind Regards

Baz